# После удаления элемента из листа, не выходит взять нужный элемент

Tags: android, adapter, arraylist, recyclerview

я делаю удаление элемента методом

```
@Override
public void remove(int position)
{
    Log.d("myLog", "lol remove");
    itemList.itemQuestions.remove(position);
    rvQuestionAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    new SaveAndLoad(getView().getContext()).Save(itemList);
}
```

Вот сам адаптер

```
rvQuestionAdapter = new RVQuestionAdapter(itemList, view.getContext(), this);

public class RVQuestionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVQuestionAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    itemList itemList = null;
    Context context;
    Resources resources;
    AddElementFragment addElementFragment;
    InterfaceAddFragment listener;

    public RVQuestionAdapter(itemList itemList, Context context, InterfaceAddFragment listener)
    {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
        //this.addElementFragment = addElementFragment;
        resources = context.getResources();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView textViewQuestion;
        LinearLayout CardDetail;
        ImageView open;
        LinearLayout edit;
        LinearLayout remove;
        TextView TrueAnswer;
        TextView FalseAnswer;
        TextView Result;
        ImageView Refresh;
        View view;

        ViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            textViewQuestion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuestion);
            CardDetail = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CardDetail);
            open = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.open);
            edit = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
            remove = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            TrueAnswer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTrue);
            FalseAnswer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFalse);
            Result = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
            Refresh = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.refresh);
            view = itemView;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_question_card, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
    {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position)
    {
        holder.textViewQuestion.setText(itemList.itemQuestions.get(position).question);
        holder.TrueAnswer.setText(resources.getString(R.string.text_TrueAnswer) + " " + itemList.itemQuestions.get(position).True);
        holder.FalseAnswer.setText(resources.getString(R.string.text_FalseAnswer) + " " + itemList.itemQuestions.get(position).False);
        holder.Result.setText(resources.getString(R.string.text_Result) + " " +
                new GetEvaluation(itemList.itemQuestions.get(position), resources).Text());

        holder.open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (holder.CardDetail.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                {
                    ExpandAndCollapce.expand(holder.CardDetail, 500);

                    ObjectAnimator rotation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation", 180);
                    rotation.setDuration(500);
                    rotation.start();
                }
                else
                {
                    ExpandAndCollapce.collapse(holder.CardDetail, 500);

                    ObjectAnimator rotation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation", 0);
                    rotation.setDuration(500);
                    rotation.start();
                }
            }
        });

        holder.edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                listener.editQuestion(position);
            }
        });

        holder.remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                listener.remove(position);
            }
        });

        holder.Refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                listener.refreshQuestion(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return itemList.itemQuestions.size();
    }
}
```

И к примеру я удалил иp списка один элемент, и потом я хочу получить последний элемент, то мне выдает

```
08-06 18:35:15.862 26812-26812/ru.landmarkstd.educt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: ru.landmarkstd.educt, PID: 26812
                                                                  Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, iconPack:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, fontPkg:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.baranovgroup.nstyle}
                                                                  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 6, size is 6
                                                                      at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                      at ru.landmarkstd.educt.Fragments.AddElementFragment.editQuestion(AddElementFragment.java:122)
                                                                      at ru.landmarkstd.educt.Adapters.RVQuestionAdapter$2.onClick(RVQuestionAdapter.java:125)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

itemList

```
    public class itemList implements Parcelable
{
    public String nameList;
    public String Tag;
    public ArrayList<itemQuestion> itemQuestions;
    public int id;

    public itemList(String nameList, String Tag, ArrayList<itemQuestion> itemQuestions, int id)
    {
        this.nameList = nameList;
        this.Tag = Tag;
        this.itemQuestions = itemQuestions;
        this.id = id;
    }

    protected itemList(Parcel in) {
        nameList = in.readString();
        Tag = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<itemList> CREATOR = new Creator<itemList>() {
        @Override
        public itemList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new itemList(in);
        }

        @Override
        public itemList[] newArray(int size) {
            return new itemList[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(nameList);
        dest.writeString(Tag);
    }
}
```

Comment: Можешь показать код ItemList?

Comment: @ИналТуаев наченм с того что это не listView, а recyclerview и код его я выложил

Comment: ах вот оно что))) (Вообще то я не писал что это listView)

Comment: удаляй элемент списка по ссылки из активити (или фрагмента). и потом вызывай rvQuestionAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

Comment: @ИналТуаев Ой, не заметил, извиняюсь )  Обновил

Comment: Во-первых: Старайся писать имена классов с большой буквы, а имена объектов - с маленькой. Это называется camelCase. Можешь почитать в интернете. Код должен быть понятен не только тебе, но и тем кому ты задаешь вопросы. Во вторых: в конструктор адаптера ты можешь передавать сразу список itemQuestions. И тогда возможно ошибка пропадет. Но я не уверен)))